# If $m\;|\;p^2k$ and $pk \lt m$, then $m$ must be $p^2k$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime and $1\le k$ be an integer.

If $m\;|\;p^2k$ and $pk \lt m$, how can I prove that $m$ must be $p^2k$?

I looks like there is no other option for $m$ since $p$ is a prime, but I can't write a formal proof.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Take $p=3,k=4,m=18$.  Then $18\,|\,(9\times 4)$ and $(3\times 4)<18$.

Comment: $p=5$, $k=2$, $m=25$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Take $m=18, p=3, k=4$. You have $m| p^2k$ and $m>pk$.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, this result is false.
Any choice of a prime $p$ and integer $k$ with $p>k$ and  $m=p^{2} $ will serve as a counterexample.
However, if we add the condition  $k | m$,
the result becomes true. From the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $m|p^{2} k$ and $k | m$ implies $m=p^{t} k$ where $t=1$ or $2$.
From the hypothesis $m>pk$, we must have $t=2$.
Therefore $m=p^{2} k$. This completes the proof.